# How do I update the listview after I delete an item?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-adapter

Every time I delete a data from firebase in the list view I visualize the data split and not correctly.
I already have the adapter but I can't handle it.
In this code I see the list view on firebase and when I click on a data item I ask the user if he wants to delete the data.
what should I do?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_elenco);

    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    //storageReference = storage.getReference();
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

    usersList = new ArrayList<>();


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("id").equalTo(firebaseUser.getUid());

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot usersSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Users users = usersSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                usersList.add(users);
                keyList.add(usersSnapshot.getKey());
            }
            UserAdapter userAdapter = new UserAdapter(Elenco.this,usersList);
            listView.setAdapter(userAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"SI","NO"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Elenco.this);
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            builder.setTitle("Vuoi eliminare la segnalazione?");
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                    if(items[i]=="SI"){
                        StorageReference photoRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://tesi-779f2.appspot.com/"+keyList.get(position));
                        photoRef.delete();
                        usersList.remove(position);
                        databaseReference.getRoot().child("Users").child(keyList.get(position)).removeValue();
                        keyList.remove(position);
                        startActivity(new Intent(Elenco.this,Profilo.class));
                    }else if(items[i]=="NO"){
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            });
            builder.show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UserAdapter userAdapter** . make this variable global over onCreate method.

and in onItemClick event after

```
keyList.remove(position);
startActivity(new Intent(Elenco.this,Profilo.class));
```

write below line.

```
userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This will update your listview.

Comment: Give this error:
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.registrazioneapp/com.example.registrazioneapp.Elenco}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Comment: can you post your full code here. so i will help you

Comment: i solver! put usersList.clear(); in onDataChange metod.

Answer (score 0):

Define a method in adapter class like this

```
public void refresh(List<Users> userList){
        this.userList=userList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and call this method whenever you made changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the data from the adapter of the listview via
`adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));`

and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on adapter.

Comment: please edit a post and tell me where to enter the code otherwise I don't understand.

Comment: check the change

Comment: not work. 
i put  notifyDataSetChanged();
but give me red error

Comment: i solver!
put          usersList.clear();

in onDataChange metod.